# layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath doesn't return the actual position when performing peek and pop

Tags: ios, iphone, 3dtouch

I am trying to implement Peek and Pop to preview the image on photo library with the following code:

```
func previewingContext(previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {
    if let indexPath = self.collectionView!.indexPathForItemAtPoint(location), cellAttributes = self.collectionView!.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) {

        previewingContext.sourceRect = cellAttributes.frame
    }

    let selectedPhotoAsset = self.allPhotos[self.selectedPhotoIndexPath![0].item] as! PHAsset

    guard let displayImageDetailVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DisplayImageDetailVC") as? DisplayImageViewController else {
        print("Error instantiate DisplayImageDetail View Controller")
        return nil
    }

    displayImageDetailVC.selectedPhotoAsset = selectedPhotoAsset

    return displayImageDetailVC
}
```

Even though it works, but the problem is after the collection view scrolled, the preview area sometimes is not at the exact cell's position when trying to peek.
[image]

Is there any way that I can get the actual position of the cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution for this issue, turns out it is related to registerForPreviewingWithDelegate.

Instead of

```
registerForPreviewingWithDelegate(self, sourceView: view)
```

It should be

```
registerForPreviewingWithDelegate(self, sourceView: self.collectionView!)
```